# Can I override a method from reference (nuget)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, overriding, nuget-package

I'm trying to override a method from referenced class. 
The class is in another solution and published as nuget package and added to my solution. 
The method is public (also in public class) and I need to make it take two arguments instead of one. 
How can I do it?

Comment: What about an extension method?

Comment: Without changing the source code, you cannot change the signature of the method. Why do you need it to take parameters anyways? Please post your code describing your problem and why you need the Method to accept 2 parameters as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I need to make it take two arguments instead of one

Then you are not overriding it, but instead providing a new method. You must obey the method signature. You can't expect other (compiled) code to suddenly understand there is actually a second argument and how to call that method then.

If the class is not sealed, it is perfectly fine to add a method in the derived class. It just is a new method, not an override of the existing method.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that, if all you want to do is extend the already present Method with more logic, an Extension method can do this

Comment: The question is about overriding. I don't want to make this overly complex for OP, but you are right, an extension method might be an option.

Comment: The point is that another solution contains a method that uses hardcoded value and I want to pass my value to that method and do same actions as it does now. If extension can help me do it, I will do it.

Comment: @LittleJohnny Then this is a x-y-Question. Please make the question about what you are trying to do. Then you can add your attempt to solve the problem and how it doesn't meet your expectations or where you are stuck. That way, people can come up with alternative solutions that actually answer the (real) question.